# Select multiple values from same column with first and second latest period date

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to get records from same column where the **MARK 1 & GRED 1** select from **SECOND LATEST RANGE PERIOD** and the **MARK 2 & GRED 2** is from **LATEST RANGE PEROID**.

**Example..**

Sam GRED 2 is from 01.01.2014 - 30.06.2014 period

Sam MARK 2 is from 01.07.2014 - 31.09.2014 period

Below is example table and desire output.

**RESULT TABLE**

```
| Name | Gred |  Mark |               SemPeriod |
|------|------|-------|-------------------------|
|  Sam |    C | 45.60 | 01.01.2013 - 30.06.2013 |
|  Sam |    B | 55.55 | 01.07.2013 - 31.12.2013 |
|  Sam |    A | 85.50 | 01.01.2014 - 30.06.2014 |
|  Sam |    C | 48.60 | 01.07.2014 - 31.09.2014 |
| Sean |    C | 45.60 | 01.01.2014 - 30.06.2014 |
| Sean |    B | 55.55 | 01.07.2014 - 31.12.2014 |
| Sean |    A | 85.50 | 01.01.2015 - 30.06.2015 |
| Sean |    C | 48.60 | 01.07.2015 - 31.12.2015 |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
| Name | Gred 1| Mark 1 | Gred 2 |  Mark 2 |  
|------|-------|--------|--------|---------|
|  Sam |    A  | 85.50  |      C |   48.60 | 
| Sean |    A  | 85.50  |      C |   48.60 |
```

I just can't get my head wrapped around this and still stuck to display the output. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type for SemPeriod  ?

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY SemPeriod_Start DESC)
    FROM   yourtable
)
SELECT  Name, 
        Gred1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Gred END),
        Mark1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Mark END),
        Gred2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Gred END),
        Mark2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Mark END)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY Name
```

if your SemPeriod is string, you should split into 2 different date column.

If not, the query will be ugly like

```
PARTITION BY Name 
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(SemPeriod , charindex('-', SemPeriod) - 1), 103) DESC
```

for large dataset, it will be slow. Also the query will break if the date range is formatted differently in the SemPeriod or there are bad data in there.

To ensure data quality, it is best to split into 2 separate date column.

Comment: SemPeriod is varchar...I just try and found probem on Mark1 & Gred1..It does not show second latest but 3rd latest..

Comment: if it is varchar, you can't simply `ORDER BY SemPeriod`

Comment: So I need to split and change data type to date?

Comment: I have read about splitting those date into 2 in select statement..but quite difficult to combine both..

Comment: possible to split into 2 column at your table ?

Comment: Thank bro..Its work..I really2 appreciated it..I need to learn more to be more skill in SQL..thank again..

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again..what happen when it conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string?..using sql server

Comment: Bad data. Check the value of that column

Comment: Can I join few table related to this query if there is student ID since I blurred how to connect to **CTE** since it like addtional function?